# Did I somehow blow these HC-SR04 sensors?

Tags: pi-3

I bought two HC-SR04 sensors, each from a different online shop. They don't have the J1-mark that signals a crappy one. I got them working the other day but then I moved them and they both stopped working. It seems that the they send random crap on the echo channel as soon as I plug them in. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/iomtcf

I use GPIO 5 for TRIG and GPIO 6 for ECHO. Here's the code (although I did try with several different ones): https://pastebin.com/nphVrQXu

The first time I wired them with R1 resistor between ECHO and GPIO 6, and R2 between GPIO 6 and GND, mostly following this: https://www.modmypi.com/blog/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi

First I had R1 = 330 Ohm, R2 = 470 Ohm, making Vout = 2.9 V approx. Now I have R1 = 330 Ohm and R2 = 660 Ohm m, making Vout about 3.3 V.

One of the sensors got very hot when I had the program running for about one hour, pinging them each minute. Can I deduce from the piscope image that the sensors are broken? I can buy new sensors but it would be nice to know how I broke them if I did.

Comment: I assume you are powering them from 5V?  I don't see how you could damage them unless you have powered from more than 5V.  Could you add a photo of one of the rangers as you connect them to the Pi?

Comment: Sure, here: https://imgur.com/a/i67L7

I forgot my breadboard at work so this is a quick solder fix. Before I had two of these connected, and the only thing I can think of that is a bit bad was that I had both Echo-pins connected via their own R1 and R2 to the same GND on the pi, instead of using a separate GND pins for each sensor. (Because that creastes a weak connection from the echo pin on sensor 1 to the echo pin on sensor 2).

Comment: I guess my question is really this: is the scatter on the echo line a sign of a broken sensor? It begins even before I run any script to send the TRIG signal.